# How to connect to database with user input in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am currently using a combination of Spring Boot, Spring JPA and Querydsl to fetch data from an oracle database. Now I want to make this service available via frontend. The user shall put in some logon credentials and I then use that information to log onto the database.

But I can't get this to work in my current project. I played around with the DataSourceBuilder but that Builder is also configured immediately on the start of the Spring Boot Application.

Is there any way to get this to work while using a Spring Boot ORM?

Comment: try directly create a database connection and operate through this connection .if you want use Spring Boot ORM you must redefine the bean.

Comment: If all the databases have an identical schema, you can look into using Hibernate's multi tenant support and create a MultiTenantConnectionProvider that will create the connection with appropriate connection details provided by your user.